# htaccess wildcard redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all my files and folders (directories) from www.example.com/* to www.example.com/website/. My current .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on

# To set your custom php.ini, add the following line to this file:
# suphp_configpath /home/yourusername/path/to/php.ini

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/website\/" [R=301,L]
Redirect 301 /* http://www.example.com/website/
```

However it is not working.

Comment: 1) (double checking) By "redirect" you mean actual 301 redirect .. or just rewrite (your example shows 301). 2) Need few "real" examples (from URL -> to URL), as it is a bit unclear how you want to  redirect (I just see some problems with your current example: `/* -> /website/`)

Comment: When someone tries to go to www.example.com/test.html, I want them really to go to www.example.com/website/test.html. When someone goes to www.example.com/documents/test.pdf, I want them to go to www.example.com/website/documents/test.pdf.

Comment: @LazyOne Do you see what I need to do now?

Comment: I've already answered on your another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website/
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/website%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Small note: I suggest using 302 code for testing and when you are happy with results change it to 301 (where required, of course). The reason -- modern browsers do cache 301 redirects .. so it may work already, but you still may see cached result.

Comment: For a complete redirect you should always remember to add QSA (Query String Append) `... [R=301,QSA,L]`